# Removing elements from vector using remove_if

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I am trying to remove vector elements using `remove_if`. But unsuccessfully. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void printme(std::vector<int>& a){
    for(const auto& item: a)
    std::cout << item << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    printme(a);  
    a.erase( (std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const int& x){
        return x == 2;
        }), a.end()));
    printme(a);
}
```

My output is just:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6

Expected output:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 3 4 5 6

Comment: Don't you get a runtime error? Your code goes out of bounds, because vector::end() points beyond the end of your vector.

Comment: @Headcrab, when I run it on cpp.sh, there was no indication of runtime error, but when I tried in later in Visual Studio, a get runtime error which points me where the problem is

Comment: why remove_if? as long as you are gonna erase, std::find is far better in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are using an overload of the `std::vector::erase()` member function that takes a single iterator as parameter. As the argument to `erase()` you are providing the iterator `a.end()`, since the following expression:

```
(std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const int& x){ return x == 2; }), a.end()))
```

evaluates to `a.end()` (i.e., because of the comma operator).

The iterator passed to the overload of `erase()` that takes a single iterator must be *dereferenceable*. However, the iterator `a.end()` is not dereferenceable, therefore, the call to `erase()` results in *undefined behavior*.

---

To use the overload that takes two iterators, remove the parenthesis surrounding the call to `std::remove_if`:

```
a.erase(std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const int& x){
        return x == 2;
        }), a.end());
```

Comment: The lesson here is that one-liners are dangerous because they're hard to read. Separating the calls to `std::remove_if` and `a.erase` can make the code much clearer.

Answer (score 8):

You're adding superfluous parentheses, change it to

```
a.erase( std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const int& x){
    return x == 2;
    }), a.end());
```

Note that the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) just returns the last operand, that means you're passing `a.end()` to `erase`, which leads to UB.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers have pointed out what the problem was. I want to say, it will be easier to notice these kinds of problems by simplifying your code.

I suggest using:

```
int main()
{
   std::vector<int> a {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
   printme(a);  

   auto it = std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const int& x){ return x == 2; });
   a.erase(it, a.end());

   printme(a);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You just had too many parentheses in the function call.

```
a.erase(std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const int& x) {return x == 2;}), a.end());
```

Just remove one parentheses before the `std::remove_if` and at the end of the call.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are doing the erase-remove idiom inline.  It is very error prone.

```
template<class C, class F>
void erase_remove_if( C&& c, F&& f ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto it = std::remove_if( begin(c), end(c), std::forward<F>(f) );
  c.erase( it, end(c) );
}
```

this little helper function does the error prone part of erase remove in isolation from other noise.

Then:

```
a.erase( (std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const int& x){
    return x == 2;
    }), a.end()));
```

becomes

```
erase_remove_if(
  a,
  [](const int& x){
    return x == 2;
  }
);
```

and suddenly your code works.

Now the proximate cause was you had a typo:

```
a.erase(
  (
    std::remove_if(
      a.begin(),
      a.end(),
      [](const int& x){
        return x == 2;
      }
    ),
    a.end()
  )
);
```

here I have expanded the line's structure.  You can see from the above that you only passed *one* argument to `erase`; namely `a.end()`, because you passed it `( some remove expression, a.end() )` in brackets.  This invoked the comma operator: so it ran the remove expression (moving the element `2` to the end), then discarded the returned iterator and evaluated to `a.end()`.

We then passed `a.end()` to `erase`, which is not a valid iterator to pass to `erase`.  So your program is ill-formed, and UB results.

That is only the *proximate* cause.  There are many mistakes you can easily make when manually doing erase-remove; the code is fragile and full of repetition.

DRY is the principle that you want a single point of customization, and you don't want to repeat things that don't need repeating.  `erase_remove_if` is my attempt to apply DRY to avoid exactly this kind of error.